# Обработка нажатия на элемент spinner

Tags: java, android

Как обработать нажатие на конкретный элемент spinner'а?

Comment: В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1):

Например можно обработать нажатия таким образом:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {    
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView adapter, View v, int i, long lng) { 
        selecteditem = adapter.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
    } 

    @Override     
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {         
    }
});
```

в функции `onItemSelected` можете добавить необходимые вам условия для выбора конкретного элемента.

Comment: Это обработка не нажатия, а изменения выбранного элемента. Если я повторно выберу один и тот же элемент, то обработчик не сработает.

Comment: @sos_mislom, и откуда я это должен был знать??)))) с учетом той информации которую вы задали в вопросе, я дал ответ, если вы уточните ваш вопрос, или хотя-бы опишите более подробно что именно вам нужно получить, то будет проще помочь

Comment: "Обработать нажатие на конкретный элемент списка" куда ещё конкретнее?))

Comment: В моем ответе вы тоже нажимаете на конкретный элемент) уточните вопрос пожалуйста

Comment: В вашем ответе не происходит обработка нажатия на конкретный элемент, как ни крути...

Comment: что значит не происходит? это стандартная функция для обработки нажатий в спиннере

Comment: Ещё раз повторяю, что нажатие, это когда нажимаешь на пункт, а слушатель, который предложили вы, может сработать не только при нажатии, а например когда выбор пункта программно меняется. Или слушатель вообще не сработает, если нажать на на уже выбранный пункт. Потому что этот слушатель не обрабатывает нажатие, а обрабатывает изменение, если для вас изменение и нажатие это одно и то же, то оставайтесь при своем мнении.